# Navigate to new destination with popUpInclusive not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

```
I went from Fragment A-> B-> C
```

From Fragment C, I need to pop to Fragment A and launch new destination Fragment D

```
In Fragment C

 <action
    android:id="@+id/action"
    app:destination="@id/new_destination" -> fragment D
    app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_B"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

or 
    
  <action
    android:id="@+id/action"
    app:destination="@id/new_destination" -> fragment D
    app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_A"
    app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>


Both these action above works, if fragment A is not refreshed with new data.. 
But when Fragment A is refreshed with new data in UI, the UI becomes weird, displays Fragment A instead of Fragment D but the icon clicks are not working
```

Code in Fragment C where the action is performed

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (resultCode) {
            
            RESULT_SUCCESS -> {
                var ids = Array of strings
                if (!ids.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action)
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does `But when Fragment A is refreshed with new data in UI` mean

Comment: When I pop from Fragment C I am getting new data from a service and refreshing Fragment with that data.. I am assuming thats causing the issue. When the UI of fragment A is not changed, it works fine

Comment: Can you include that code and where you're triggering your action?

Comment: updated  with code

Comment: I meant the code in Fragment A that you refer to when you said "But when Fragment A is refreshed with new data in UI, the UI becomes weird, displays Fragment A instead of Fragment D but the icon clicks are not working". It is hard to understand what Fragment A (which is on the back stack and isn't started) has to do with an action on Fragment C working or not working without that code.

Comment: Fragment A is a tab fragment, which is a grid view.. we get devices from server and update the grid view.. So when Fragment C pops up to Fragment A, onResume Fragment A refresh the devices and update the UI which a new gridview.. The title bar is updated with Fragment D. When I click anywhere in teh Fragment A gridview.. it doesn't work

Comment: If you are using that action, Fragment A should not be resumed on your way to Fragment D.